# Make MotionLayout in android expand fully in screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I have an app where i'm animating two views to expand and collapse accordingly against each others , for direction i'm using drag up , inside my xml file i have a recyclerView which only make motion layout as much as its content whereas i want the motionlayout to expand even up , any idea Thank you in advance .

- This is my motion_layout_start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curvy_black_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/str"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

- This is my motion_scene_end layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/curvy_black_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/str"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- This is layout description xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@layout/activity_main_motion_scene_end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@layout/activity_main_motion_scene_start" >

        <OnSwipe app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:onTouchUp="stop"
            app:autoCompleteMode="spring"/>
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

- This is an image from my app ( i have drawn that horizontal red line to show that's the max it expands based on recycler content , but i want it to expand fully )

[image]

Comment: Where is the MotionLayout?

Comment: @hoford i have updated the code if you want to take a look , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**The main problem**

It looks like you are trying to drag the `LinearLayout` up
But do not define `motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/linearLayout"`

```xml
        <OnSwipe 
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/linearLayout"
         />
```

additional OnSwipe arguments would modify the default behavior.
Based on preferences.

**Secondary problem**

Looking at only attributes. You are going from:

```
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

to

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

The `LinearLayout` goes from 50% below the screen to  wrap_content. I am not sure what is meant to happen here.
There are many possible effects you want.

If you want to hide extra off screen you could have the start look like this

```xml
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

But there are many possibilities.